# Why git is too slow to push large files? Is there any way then to optimize it or ignore it?

Tags: linux, git, netbeans, github

I have many large files under project/public/deploy/. All the rest is my source codes. When i pushed yesterday, still today its not complete yet, and my network is dead slow for this. I understand its because i have largest files and getting pushed, which is like impossible.

How can i tell git push do not ever push the directory, project/public/deploy/?

```
project/
./application/<all source codes>
./framework/<all source codes>
./public/deploy/download/archlinux.fedora.centos.freebsd.isos.tar.gz
./public/deploy/tutorial/oracle.bigtable.mysql.db2.why.mp4
./public/deploy/tutorial/c.cpp.java.d.vala.tutorial.episode1.mp4
./public/deploy/tutorial/c.cpp.java.d.vala.tutorial.episode2.mp4
./public/deploy/tutorial/c.cpp.java.d.vala.tutorial.episode3.mp4
./public/deploy/tutorial/hacking.android.linux.mp4
```

Is there any way to put a push flag or put a tiny gitignore file in a direcotry where it can ignore everything? (before trakking and after tracking, when-ever there is a ignore suggestion it will always/forever ignore that directory unless i remove it?)

Comment: Have you tried a `.gitignore` file with a wildcard `*` in it, in a single line?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: its not working. Once upon a time (Day 0), i did this $ touch project/public/deploy/download/archlinux.fedora.centos.freebsd.isos.tar.gz; and long before i did a push, which created an empty file, and its tracking. Now if i put .gitignore it seems not working because its in track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Large binary files should not live inside your project. Git is not the right tool for that job as you have noticed. The files should be ignored in your project's `.gitignore`. Add a line like `public/deploy/tutorial/*.mp4` (or less specific if you want).

Now, as the files are already in your repository, you need to amend the history of your repository. Github has a [tutorial](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) on this subject, which boils down to:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch public/deploy/tutorial/*.mp4' \
  --prune-empty -- --all
```

Now that the repository has been cleaned, you can push it. It should complete as fast as usually.

Comment: Good point. Can you suggest any solution for him how to share or sync the video files after that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the video files to be followed by Git. Even if they are in constant development and get changed every now and then, you might just index the project file of your video editor or something alike.

However, I'd suggest you break your huge project into smaller ones. E.g. I guess `application/` code relies on the `framework/` code but changes in those folders are independent as long as the API isn't broken. So why not putting them into 2 Git projects?

For the large video files I'd suggest putting them on a central file share and doing syncs. If several people change that every day you might find a solution to share only the project file. Ask another question for details of that.

I never used this before but it can be very handy: Git supports subprojects. That means you can integrate another Git repository in your tree and Git will fetch its commits but the code base and the history are independent and don't get that large. Maybe this is the right approach for the connection from `application/` to `framework/`.